# how to efficiently index and search ipv4 address ranges in c#

Tags: c#, data-structures, hash

I have about 90000 IPv4 address ranges with data associated with each range

e.g.

```
1.0.0.0 - 1.1.0.0 ->  "foo"
2.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.0 -> "bar"
```

Given an IP address, I need to retrieve the associated data. How can I do this **efficiently**?

I guess I can make things easier by converting the addresses to a single integer, but what data structure would be best to use to store this to enable **fast** searching?

**Clarification** - I'm searching with single IP, not a range (e.g. "192.168.0.1")

Thanks

Comment: IPv4 addresses are just 32bit ints. Store them as such and searching becomes trivial.

Comment: These ranges do not overlap, do they?

Comment: @AndrewBullock how are ranges and data currently represented in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the ends of the non-overlapping intervals in a single array. Mark each end with a flag indicating if it is the beginning or the end of the interval, like this:

```
1.0.0.0 1.1.0.0 2.0.0.0 10.0.0.0
 start   end     start    end
```

Now run a binary search with the target address, say, `3.2.1.0`. The insertion point falls on `2.0.0.0`, which is marked as `start`. This means that `3.2.1.0` is one of the intervals.

Now consider searching for `1.2.3.4`. Its insertion point falls on `1.1.0.0`, which is marked as `end`. Since `1.2.3.4` is not equal to the `1.1.0.0`, we know that `1.2.3.4` is not one of the intervals.

The cost of a search is `Log(N)`, where `N` is the number of intervals.

If you feel adventurous, consider implementing an [`interval tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). This is probably not worth it for non-overlapping intervals, though.

Comment: i like this, seems to make considerable sense :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to support IPv4 addresses and not IPv6 addresses, you can store each address as an `UInt32`. That will make comparing them very easy and efficient.

If the IP ranges doesn't overlap, and you can keep them sorted in a list, you can use a varition of a binary search to quickly find a range.

Comment: What if you have a range of 10000 sequential IPs? You store 10000 ints? You could store 2 ints! (First and Last in range). It's fast retrieval with appropriate indexing, but it is NOT memory-efficient.

Comment: Very possible. Were you only talking about how to store the IP itself? If so, it doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail please? i understand binary searching, but how does this help me find which range my ip belongs to?

Comment: ah i suppose all i really need to find is the start of the range, as if the list is ordered the next range start will be greater than my value. yes... all becomes clear

Comment: @AndrewBullock: To find the range you could simply loop throught the ranges and check if the address is in the range. Using binary search only changes which ranges you compare the address to, reducing the number or comparisons from by average 45000 to at most 17.

Answer (score 0):

Finding whether numbers from 0 to 20 including, with the following ranges:

```
2-5 -> "a"
6-7 -> "b"
9-11 -> "c"
12-12 -> "d"
15-18 -> "e"
19-19 -> "f"
```

Inside a loop for 1,000,000 times, including 1 times creation and initialization of RangeCollection: Only 3 seconds!

All that is left for you to do is prepare an IEnumerable of Tuple where the first int is minimum IP int-value, the second is the maximum, and the TValue is the data that is associated with that min~max range.

Here is my implementation:

```
public class RangeCollection<TValue>
{
    private readonly int[] _mins;
    private readonly int[] _maxs;
    private readonly TValue[] _values;

    public RangeCollection(params Tuple<int, int, TValue>[] input)
        : this((IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, TValue>>)input)
    {
    }

    public RangeCollection(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, TValue>> input)
    {
        var tuples = input.OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item1).ToArray();

        for (var i = 1; i < tuples.Length; i++)
        {
            if (tuples[i].Item1 <= tuples[i - 1].Item2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Ranges should not overlap.");
            }
        }

        this._mins = new int[tuples.Length];
        this._maxs = new int[tuples.Length];
        this._values = new TValue[tuples.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < tuples.Length; i++)
        {
            var tuple = tuples[i];

            this._mins[i] = tuple.Item1;
            this._maxs[i] = tuple.Item2;
            this._values[i] = tuple.Item3;
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(int key, out TValue value)
    {
        if (this.Contains(key, out key))
        {
            value = this._values[key];
            return true;
        }

        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Contains(int key)
    {
        return this.Contains(key, out key);
    }

    private bool Contains(int key, out int index)
    {
        index = 0;

        if (this._mins.Length == 0 || key < this._mins[0] || key > this._maxs[this._maxs.Length - 1])
        {
            return false;
        }

        var low = 0;
        var high = this._mins.Length - 1;

        while (high >= low)
        {
            index = (low + high) / 2;

            var cmp = this._mins[index].CompareTo(key);

            if (cmp == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (cmp == 1)
            {
                high = index - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                low = index + 1;
            }
        }

        if (this._mins[index] > key)
        {
            index--;
        }
        else if (this._mins[index + 1] <= key)
        {
            index++;
        }

        return this._maxs[index] >= key;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var collection = new RangeCollection<string>(new Tuple<int, int, string>(2, 5, "a"),
                                             new Tuple<int, int, string>(6, 7, "b"),
                                             new Tuple<int, int, string>(9, 11, "c"),
                                             new Tuple<int, int, string>(12, 12, "d"),
                                             new Tuple<int, int, string>(15, 18, "e"),
                                             new Tuple<int, int, string>(19, 19, "f"));

for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    string val;
    if (collection.TryGetValue(i, out val))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Contains {0}. Value: {1}", i, val);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Doesn't contain " + i);
    }
}

/* Output:

Doesn't contain 0
Doesn't contain 1
Contains 2. Value: a
Contains 3. Value: a
Contains 4. Value: a
Contains 5. Value: a
Contains 6. Value: b
Contains 7. Value: b
Doesn't contain 8
Contains 9. Value: c
Contains 10. Value: c
Contains 11. Value: c
Contains 12. Value: d
Doesn't contain 13
Doesn't contain 14
Contains 15. Value: e
Contains 16. Value: e
Contains 17. Value: e
Contains 18. Value: e
Contains 19. Value: f
Doesn't contain 20

*/
```